# Getting jQuery error on click -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not an jQuery expert and I would like to know if I am doing something wrong that generate errors in jQuery when clicking on 2 icons I have in a simple table.

In the specific [here](https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wohnen/) when I click on the pdf icon or on the envelope icon I see in console that an error is generate (the number increase every time I click on one of the 2 icons). Plus, the links I set for the icons are not working anymore.

On the right as you can see I have an animation. This is simply script code that I deactivated to see if was that the problem but it didn't worked.

Unfortunately I am using a plugin for the CMS and I cannot change it's code.

This is the error

```
(index):62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> ((index):62)
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLTableElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
```

This is the code

```
//your current click function
$('.scroll').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px'
    },1000,'swing');
});
```

Comment: it's because you selector returns an attribute 'string' not an element

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a class to the links for those two icons, e.g. I add class="clickable":

```
<a class="clickable" href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C16-0.2.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" height="20" width="auto"></a>
```

Then add this to your javascript:

```
$(".clickable, .clickable img").on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

So that the scroll javascript code doesn't run when you click on these two links.

Comment: You mean like that?
```<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".clickable, .clickable img").on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
});
</script>```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the script:

```js
//your current click function
$('.scroll').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href'), $ele = $(href);
    if ($ele && $ele.offset()) {
      var top = $ele.offset().top + 'px'
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:top
      },1000,'swing');
    }   
});
```